# Need to press back button twice to navigate back from activity

Tags: android

I have a main activity A (PlacesListActivity). It calls activity B (AboutMeActivity) from the navigation drawer. I have declared activity A as the parent activity of B in manifest.

Now, when I go from A->B,

- if i press the back arrow in action bar, it takes me back to the activity A.
- regarding the hardware button, I have to press it twice to go back to activity A. When I press hardware back once, nothing happens. It seems like it just reloads activity B. 
  I don't want this. Pressing hardware button once should do the job.

Code for activity B :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_me);
    initialize();
}

 private void initialize() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarAboutMe);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   .....
 }
```

initialize function just initializes some UI elements.

Code for calling activity B :

```
@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    Intent i;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            i = new Intent(this, AboutMeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
            ......
```

Manifest :

```
<activity
        android:name="....AboutMeActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="....PlacesListActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="....PlacesListActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Edit :

I have tried with overriding `OnBackPressed()`, but it never gets called.

tried with overriding `OnKeyDown()` and calling `finish()` in that, but still, I have to press it twice to go back to activity A.

Comment: is in Activity B the Softkeyboard active or something else in focus then the Activity itself? If u override OnBackPressed() in Activity B it should work just fine when the activity in focused.

Comment: had you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the search component did have the focus when I press the hardware back button

Doing this solved my problem :

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    searchInputView?.clearFocus() //searchInputView is initialized in onCreateOptionsMenu
}
```

So generally speaking, be sure that the back button is correclty catched by the activity and not by a subcomponent of your activity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just override the onBackPressed method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   finish();
}
```

also keep in mind the [BackStack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

Handle onBackPressed event in Activity B

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {      
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish(); // to close this activity
            //finish() or start another activity 
    }
```